# Where to store frontend display data

Tags: user-interface, frontend, web-frontend

We have a Rest API that is called by a front end. For example to get a list types to be displayed in a drop down list.
The list of items is stores in the database. However the text representation displayed in front end is stored in a translate file in the front end.
If the front end team has a wish that the items are sorted in a specific way, and a wish that a specific item in the list is the default selected item, where should this information be stored? In database or somewhere in frontend?
I would argue that since it has nothing to do with backend business logic, it should be stored in the front end.
But I am in doubt. Any comments would be great

Comment: Is it a user based thing or a global thing? If it's global, it would make sense to put it in the DB, i.e., you'd add an `OrderBy` field to the table and utilise that.

Comment: It is a global thing. But my issue is that it is a value only used for visualization. There is no business logic that needs the ordering. So why not store it in front end. Same as translation files that contain all texts to be shown. They are not stored in backend database

Comment: Could the `orderby` also be used in reports? (that might be built in an external system). Could this list be increased? If both these things are true then there as an argument to put OrderBy in the DB. If both these things are false, then there is probably no issue in putting this in the front end